# bifurcating the cumulative _sum based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

I have table "cumul_sum" in mysql here I want to divide the column "cumulative" based on a condition i.e if the value in this column is >= 70 then those values should be stored in a new column called as "others" and should store the corresponding sku_id in front of it ,here is the structure of mytable

```
sku_id   cumulative
  1         10
  20        20
  13        30
  24        50
  9         80 
  4         100
```

this is what I'm expecting

```
sku_id    cumulative    sku_id_1    others
 1           10            9         80
 20          20            4         100 
 13          30
 24          50


Is this any way possible
```

if yes please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: May I ask why do you have to have it in a new column?

Comment: because I want to show the column whose value is greater than 70 and the column value less than 70 in one table

Comment: For what purpose? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: What you are asking do not look like something usual in MySQL. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a another way to do it in MySQL. If not, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that what you are trying to achieve is efficient and scalable but that might do the work.

```
SET @row = 0;
SET @row2 = 0;
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS row, 
        sku_id, 
        cumulative, 
        s.sku_id_1 as 'sku_id_1', 
        s.others as 'others'
FROM `cumul_sum`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT (@row2:=@row2+1) AS 'row', 
           sku_id AS 'sku_id_1', 
           cumulative as 'others'
           FROM `cumul_sum`
           WHERE `others` >= 70) s ON `cumul_sum`.`row` = `s`.`row`
WHERE `cumul_sum`.`cumulative` < 70;
```

Comment: I used your code, its throwing an error                                                                  error code 1054 unknown column 'others' in 'where clause', I tried replacing 'others' with 'cumulative'(column name) but still left with error.

Comment: Nope its not working and giving me the same error "error code 1054 unknown column 'others' in 'where clause'," .  :(

Answer (score 1):

That doesnt looks like a job for a sql query, instead you should process that format in the UI.

so just create two querys.

```
SELECT sku_id, comulative
FROM YourTable
WHERE comulative < 70 

SELECT sku_id, comulative as others
FROM YourTable
WHERE comulative >= 70
```

and if you are displaying on php or something similar (this isnt real code)

```
$size1 = query1.length;
$size2 = query2.length;
if ($size1`> $size2)
    $total = $size1
else 
    $total = $size2

<table>
for ($i = 1 to $total)
{
   <tr>
       <td> if ($i <= $size1) echo $query1[$i]; </td>
       <td> if ($i <= $size2) echo $query2[$i]; </td>
   </tr>
}
</table>
```